# Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 with Jupgrade. "undefined migrating error"

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla1.5

I've try to migrate a website in Joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 using jUpgrade but I've receive the "undefined migrating" error.

[image: "undefined migrating" error]

The files was correctly transferred, but there's no change to the db, and when I try to log on `website.com/jupgrade`, I land on a page saying "please delete installation folder" and no db was transferred/created (so I have to create it manually and create menu, article, etc. wasting so much time!)

Please help. I have already tried removing folder and changing `tmp` to 777 permission (with `chmod`) and nothing changed!

**Update: 2012-07-24
Getting more information while running jupdate in debug mode:

> "========== [checks]
>
> 1
>
> ========== [cleanup]
>
> 1
>
> ========== [decompress]
>
> 1
>
> ========== [install_config]
>
> ========== [install_db]
>
> ========== [undefined] [undefined]
>
> jos-Error: Table 'name_joomla.j25_users' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT
>   INTO `j25_users`
>   (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`,`activation`,`params`)
>   VALUES
>   ('62','Administrator','admin','email@company.com','d7bfdb4f0aa91c9618b2969f4b91006e:jJzEVXG7VDz0u95RQu06CQPMFsxCic4e','Super
>   Administrator','0','1','2011-12-16 14:37:40','2012-07-24
>   13:57:43','','{\"admin_language\":\"\",\"language\":\"\",\"editor\":\"\",\"helpsite\":\"\",\"timezone\":\"UTC\"}')
>   "

Comment: go to your Joomla backend and then go to `Help >> System Information >> Directory Permissions` and make sure all the folder mentioned are "writable"

Comment: It looks like a lot of people are having the same problem...

Comment: I've check the permission, all is fine.. :( adding more info (from this morning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally working - at this point - following the 1st solution from @wiki.redcomponent.com by removing all the plugins and **reinstalling another version** (from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2)

**"Migrating undefined" or "[undefined][undefined]"**

There may come an instance where the process will get stuck while migrating data for a specific component and (with "Debug mode" enabled) an error similar to "Migrating undefined" or "[undefined][undefined]" will be displayed.

**Some causes and remedies include:**
a migrate_xxx.php file that is being requested for by jUpgrade is not available or accessible

(these files are stored in the {root}/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/ folder, labelled "migrate_xxx.php" where "xxx" is the section of content being transferred at the time.)

> **To fix: uninstall and reinstall jUpgrade (to restore all required
>   files) and try again.**[Get jupgrade 2.5.2](http://redcomponent.com/free-downloads/cat_view/931-jupgrade)**

• The database table from which content is being transferred is corrupt or has been modified 
(jUpgrade requires that no modifications have been made to any of the core tables themselves, otherwise the migration can run into problems when dealing with custom fields)

> To fix:download and install a maintenance component such as "Admin
>   Tools!" and run a database integrity check and repair. Alternatively
>   the database may have to be repaired manually using "phpmyadmin" or a
>   similar interface. A solution for databases with custom fields is
>   being looked into, but for the moment those must be migrated manually,
>   or if they interfere with the migration, removed. (Of course a backup
>   should be run before any such operation.)

• The migration runs into an issue attempting to copy content over to a database which already has content (from a previous migration, failed or not).

> To fix: remove all the tables created for the new Joomla! install
>   during the migration and run jUpgrade again.

• the Javascript which handles the migration process has run into a problem

> To fix:check in the Plugin Manager to ensure that any system plugins
>   related to javascript libraries, apart from the "MooTools Upgrade"
>   plugin (which is required) has been disabled and try running jUpgrade
>   again. *let's give up IE and try Chrome ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it workd the followng way:
After first attempt to install joomla 2.5 with Jupgrade it stucked at migrating. I checked the mysql tables and saw that about 15 of them were new j25 tables.
So I suposed it is stuck somewhere and tried again by going again in jupgrade component and pressing again the upgrade button. It was stuck again so I checked the mysql and saw that new 10 tables were made. So I just tried one more time an it worked this time. It created all mysql tables and upgraded joomla from 1.5.26 to 2.5.2.
The ony think I did before that is extracting manually the joomla25.zip in the target directory for the new installation and then I disabled the download, decompression and checks settings in Jupgrade.
Hope this works for someone else :)