# joomla jupgrade from 1.5 to 2.5 "migrating undefined"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I am having no luck upgrading from joomla 1.5 to 2.5 with jupgrade... I have tried everything it seems. I kept getting stuck in the decompressing stage so I went and followed the manual instructions and was able to bypass those steps. Now I'm stuck at the upgrading process getting a migrating undefined error. I am noticing that the db is getting updated with the new prefixed tables but the third party components/plugins are not getting converted. These tables are also empty so no migration is taking place. It is like it is getting half way through and then getting stuck on something.

I have tried everything suggested here: http://wiki.redcomponent.com/index.php?title=jUpgrade:Troubleshooting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Duplicate entry '62' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `j25_users` (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`,`activation`,`params`)
```

This is the error I'm getting now. I still get migrating undefined on the users table but then it moves on and then get hung up on 3rd party extensions. My problem is I have gone into the table manually and investigated for the dup but there isn't one. I even deleted the user and am still getting the error.

Any ideas what I should do? Advice.
Thanks

Comment: Hey I posted the errors. Can anyone help decipher? What I should do?

Comment: When I remove the entry shown above I just get an error for the next entry in line. This seems a bit more complicated than just a dup as there is no dup...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (a dozen sites migrated) the cause is often different, just check the error logs.  Usually the issue lies with an extension that added fields to #__content or another system table.  Read the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Finally working - at this point - following the 1st solution from @wiki.redcomponent.com by removing all the plugins and **reinstalling another version** (from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2)

**"Migrating undefined" or "[undefined][undefined]"**

There may come an instance where the process will get stuck while migrating data for a specific component and (with "Debug mode" enabled) an error similar to "Migrating undefined" or "[undefined][undefined]" will be displayed.

**Some causes and remedies include:**
a migrate_xxx.php file that is being requested for by jUpgrade is not available or accessible

(these files are stored in the {root}/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/ folder, labelled "migrate_xxx.php" where "xxx" is the section of content being transferred at the time.)

> **To fix: uninstall and reinstall jUpgrade (to restore all required
>   files) and try again.**[Get jupgrade 2.5.2](http://redcomponent.com/free-downloads/cat_view/931-jupgrade)**

• The database table from which content is being transferred is corrupt or has been modified 
(jUpgrade requires that no modifications have been made to any of the core tables themselves, otherwise the migration can run into problems when dealing with custom fields)

> To fix:download and install a maintenance component such as "Admin
>   Tools!" and run a database integrity check and repair. Alternatively
>   the database may have to be repaired manually using "phpmyadmin" or a
>   similar interface. A solution for databases with custom fields is
>   being looked into, but for the moment those must be migrated manually,
>   or if they interfere with the migration, removed. (Of course a backup
>   should be run before any such operation.)

• The migration runs into an issue attempting to copy content over to a database which already has content (from a previous migration, failed or not).

> To fix: remove all the tables created for the new Joomla! install
>   during the migration and run jUpgrade again.

• the Javascript which handles the migration process has run into a problem

> To fix:check in the Plugin Manager to ensure that any system plugins
>   related to javascript libraries, apart from the "MooTools Upgrade"
>   plugin (which is required) has been disabled and try running jUpgrade
>   again. *let's give up IE and try Chrome ;-)*

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620390/joomla-1-5-to-2-5-with-jupgrade-undefined-migrating-error#answer-11634574)

Comment: Yea I read this... Not working.

Comment: can you explain this better? removing all the plugins and reinstalling another version (from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2)